# drawable not showing when using "" app:passwordToggleEnabled=true "" in TextInputLayout android

Tags: java, android, xml

When i use `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` for TextInputLayout , the left drawable doesn't show anymore.
here is my xml code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

(this is just happening in buildTool version 25.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"`
Instead of

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, but my min Api is 14. any advice ?

Comment: Happy Coding.. :)